# Sort python list by individual letters of strings

Tags: python

I have a python list as follows:

```
['a', 'c', 'ab', 'abc', 'bc', 'b']
```

I need the output as:

```
['a', 'ab', 'abc','b', 'bc', 'c']
```

To build the original list, my code is:

```
def  buildString( s):
    arr = []
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        for j in range(i, len(s)):
            temp = ''
            for k in range(i, j+1):
                temp += s[k]
                arr.append(temp)
    x = set(arr)
    result = list(x)
    return result

print buildString('abc')
```

This program is to build complete subsequences of an input string in lexicographic order

Comment: What's wrong with `sorted(your_list)`?

Comment: @user2357112 Oh my god..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `sort` it. Use `sorted` or `list.sort`.

```
In [126]: a = ['a', 'c', 'ab', 'abc', 'bc', 'b']
In [127]: sorted(a)
Out[127]: ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'b', 'bc', 'c']

In [128]: a.sort()

In [129]: a
Out[129]: ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'b', 'bc', 'c']
```

[Go through](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) for learn about sorting in python.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it's the most obvious answer. Sorry about this.

Comment: @Newtt please mark correct if  you find my answer helping to promote me on SO.

Comment: Yes, it'l allow me to accept in 7 minutes.